# Overflow-x:Scroll is not working on chrome browser (scroll bar does not move with grid content)

Tags: javascript, css, google-chrome, overflow, ag-grid

I have a grid defined with a horizontal scrollbar using ag-grid. When I click the left or right spacer, only the scrollbar moves, but not the grid content.
The problem occurs with Chrome, Edge.

It didn't work with any of the CSS styles I tried. Additionally, I wrote browser-specific code, but it didn't work. Scroll bar should move along with grid content

Here is my Grid.html file,I have used ag-grid documentation as reference for creating below Data grid

'''

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta
      name="viewport"
      content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"
    />
    <title>My Data Grid</title>
        <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/ag-grid-community/dist/ag-grid-community.min.noStyle.js"></script>

    <link rel="stylesheet"
      href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/ag-grid-community/styles/ag-grid.css"/>
    
    <link rel="stylesheet"
      href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/ag-grid-community/styles/ag-theme-alpine.css"/>
  </head>
  <body>
        <div id="myGrid" class="ag-theme-alpine" style="height: 500px"></div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        const columnDefs = [
                            { field: "SerialNo" },
                            { field: "Name" },
                            { field: "Project" },
                            { field: "JoiningDate" },
                            { field: "JobRole" },
                            { field: "RoleBand" },
                            { field: "EmployeeType" },
                            { field: "Contact" },
                            { field: "ReportingManager" }
                           ];

                const rowData = [
                        { SerialNo: 1, Name: "A", Project: "Del100", JoiningDate: "DD-MM-YY" , JobRole: "Associate" , RoleBand: "RB7" , EmployeeType: "Regular" , Contact: "xxxxxx" , ReportingManager: "xyz" },
                        { SerialNo: 2, Name: "B", Project: "Del100", JoiningDate: "DD-MM-YY" , JobRole: "QA" , RoleBand: "RB6" , EmployeeType: "Regular" , Contact: "xxxxxx" , ReportingManager: "xyz" },
                        { SerialNo: 3, Name: "C", Project: "Del200", JoiningDate: "DD-MM-YY" , JobRole: "Developer" , RoleBand: "RB5" , EmployeeType: "Contract" , Contact: "xxxxxx" , ReportingManager: "xyz" },
                        { SerialNo: 4, Name: "D", Project: "Del500", JoiningDate: "DD-MM-YY" , JobRole: "Associate" , RoleBand: "RB7" , EmployeeType: "Regular" , Contact: "xxxxxx" , ReportingManager: "xyz" },
                        { SerialNo: 5, Name: "E", Project: "Del110", JoiningDate: "DD-MM-YY" , JobRole: "Associate" , RoleBand: "RB7" , EmployeeType: "Part-Time" , Contact: "xxxxxx" , ReportingManager: "xyz" },
                        { SerialNo: 6, Name: "F", Project: "Del100", JoiningDate: "DD-MM-YY" , JobRole: "Developer" , RoleBand: "RB5" , EmployeeType: "Regular" , Contact: "xxxxxx" , ReportingManager: "xyz" },
                        { SerialNo: 7, Name: "G", Project: "Del110", JoiningDate: "DD-MM-YY" , JobRole: "Automation" , RoleBand: "RB4" , EmployeeType: "Contract" , Contact: "xxxxxx" , ReportingManager: "xyz" },
                        { SerialNo: 8, Name: "H", Project: "Del100", JoiningDate: "DD-MM-YY" , JobRole: "Developer" , RoleBand: "RB5" , EmployeeType: "Regular" , Contact: "xxxxxx" , ReportingManager: "xyz" },
                        { SerialNo: 9, Name: "I", Project: "Del110", JoiningDate: "DD-MM-YY" , JobRole: "Automation" , RoleBand: "RB4" , EmployeeType: "Contract" , Contact: "xxxxxx" , ReportingManager: "xyz" },
                        { SerialNo: 10, Name: "J", Project: "Del200", JoiningDate: "DD-MM-YY" , JobRole: "QA" , RoleBand: "RB6" , EmployeeType: "Contract" , Contact: "xxxxxx" , ReportingManager: "xyz" },
                        { SerialNo: 11, Name: "K", Project: "Del100", JoiningDate: "DD-MM-YY" , JobRole: "Developer" , RoleBand: "RB5" , EmployeeType: "Part-Time" , Contact: "xxxxxx" , ReportingManager: "xyz" },
                        { SerialNo: 12, Name: "L", Project: "Del300", JoiningDate: "DD-MM-YY" , JobRole: "Automation" , RoleBand: "RB4" , EmployeeType: "Regular" , Contact: "xxxxxx" , ReportingManager: "xyz" },
                        { SerialNo: 13, Name: "M", Project: "Del300", JoiningDate: "DD-MM-YY" , JobRole: "QA" , RoleBand: "RB6" , EmployeeType: "Part-Time" , Contact: "xxxxxx" , ReportingManager: "xyz" },
                        
                        ];

        
        const gridOptions = {
            columnDefs: columnDefs,
            rowData: rowData,

          
          defaultColDef: {sortable: true, filter: true},

          rowSelection: 'multiple', 
          animateRows: true, 

          
          onCellClicked: params => {
            alert('cell was clicked', params)
          }
        };

        
        const eGridDiv = document.getElementById("myGrid");
        
        new agGrid.Grid(eGridDiv, gridOptions);
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

'''

Any suggestions will be helpful for me

Comment: Without the re-produce code it would be hard for us to help you. But you can try:

1. Set overflow-x auto for the grid container:
```css
.container {
  overflow-x: auto;
}
```

2. Change (domLayout)[https://www.ag-grid.com/angular-data-grid/grid-options/#reference-rendering-domLayout] to "autoHeight":
```ts
gridOptions: {
  domLayout: 'autoHeight', // or 'autoHeight,pagination' if using pagination
  // Other grid options...
}
```

Comment: I have shared reproducible code, any help will be appreciated